# Different null comparison?

Tags: java, android

What it's the difference between this two codes?:

**Code 1**

In my first code I have a variable in which I put directly that it is null.

```
String prove = null;

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), prove, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 

if(prove == null)
{
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "correct", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
else
{
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "incorrect", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

**Result 1**

```
null
correct
```

---

**Code 2**

In my second code I have a class named `Car` with his `GET` and `SET` methods but the method that have to return the `String` return null.

```
public class Car {

    private int idCar;
    private String name;

    public Car(){};

    public Car(int idCar, String name)
    {
        this.idCar = idCar;
        this.name = name;
    }

    //Here the rest of GET and SET methods

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
}
```

And in my `MainActivity.java` I have an `ArrayList` of `Cars`:

```
ArrayList<Car> cars = new ArrayList<Car>();
```

That I use on my CustomAdapter, as follows:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), cars.get(position).getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

if(cars.get(position).getName() == null)
{
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "correct", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
else
{
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "incorrect", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

**Result 2**

```
null
incorrect
```

What is the difference between both codes? Apparently they are similar because in both of them I compare a `String` that it's `null` vs `null` but their behaviour it's different.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure the string is `null` and not `"null"` ?

Comment: Can you please show the code where you instanciate the Car which later has name not null and leads to the "incorrect" toast?

Comment: `cars(position)` is not valid syntax for accesing Arraylist item, looks like what you have shown as code is not real code.   Besides, what stops you from putting a breakpoint in your code and debug the value of `getName()`

Comment: Now put a breakpoint in code and inspect the value

Answer (score 2):

These two codes are *worlds apart* in what they're doing.

In your first example, you explicitly set a variable to `null` and are comparing against `null`.  This can be reasoned with; the code path that you exercise doesn't directly change the value to something that's non-`null`, so it would make *perfect sense* that you see your Toast with "correct".

In your second example, you do two different things:

- You create a `Toast` right off the bat with text from `cars(position).getName()`
- You then check if `cars(position).getName()` is `null` or not.  The likely scenario is that it *isn't* and shows the other path.

If you wanted to make them at least similar, you would do well to move `cars(position).getName()` to a variable...

```
String prove = cars(position).getName();

if(prove == null) {
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "correct", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} else {
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "incorrect", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

I did a quick dive into the source code for `Toast`, and if the string you provide it is `null` it will supply you with an empty string instead (or a toast that's blank).  You haven't indicated that you're not seeing text in the second toast that you provided, so I would presume that the value you're getting for `cars(position).getName()` is not null.

Comment: I'm retrieving the info from a database and in my database the value `Name` of this car it's null. It's why I supposed that it would be the same result in both codes. In the result I put what I got from both codes by `Toast`. And I also tried doing `String prove = cars(position).getName();` but the result it's the same. It returns me that it is null (in the Toast) but inside the `if`, it goes to the Toast that say that it is incorrect. I'm still confused about it.

Comment: It depends how you get the data from the database, i.e. whether the code you use returns a Java null or a string "null".

Comment: @JonathanRosenne When I create a new row on the database it is created as a Java null but when I retrieve the info from the database with the JSONObject I got it as `obj.getString`. I though it was retrieving to me a Java null (as I stored it), but maybe it is coming as "null". How can I know that?

Comment: @Error404:  If you print the object out, does it say "null"?  I'd capture the object in a variable and print both the variable and its boolean comparison against `null`.  Or, if you have a debugger/IDE, inspect it in the debugger.

Comment: @Makoto In both Toast, using directly null or retrieving it from the method getName() I saw in my screen the message null. But it doesn't have double quotes or something that let me difference between null or "null".